# ajax status = 0

Tags: javascript, ajax, status

i'm trying to get information from a remote server on my local machine.
readyState has no problem, i.e. ==4. however, status is always 0(instead of 200)
when I hit the button, it returns nothing.

here is the code,:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET",'http://www.spartanbook.com/textbooks_xml.asp?control=campus&campus=45&term=80',true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

It's basically from w3shcools. simply replaced the url.
the url I'm using is working when I paste it into address bar of my browser.

Any idea?
Thanks!!

Comment: "Any idea?": Don't use w3schools :-) http://w3fools.com/

Comment: It doesn't work, because [W3Schools is bad](http://w3fools.com/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check that you are not making a cross domain request.

If for example you are not serving this page from http://www.spartanbook.com then the expected result would be access denied, which oddly enough gives a readyState of 4, but a status of 0.

If you need to make a cross domain request, then you need to use a proxy.

Comment: Gavin, I CAN access the content by browser, but can't do it from code. so I guess it won't relate to domain.

Comment: @user788072: That's exactly the point-- cross-domain policy applies to JavaScript asynchronous requests in JavaScript code. Of course you can access it in your browser-- your browser can access any domain!

Comment: +1 to offset the possible ill-informed downvote, until whoever downvoted comes out and explains why and there's actually a good reason.

Comment: Hi Cheng.  You need to pass your request through a local proxy.  Please take a look at this link as an example. [link](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/cross-domain-ajax-querying-with-jquery.html)

Answer (score 0):

This error code indicates that the response was empty. Seems like a firewall issue

Comment: firewall from my side or their side?

Answer (score 0):

Like Gavin says, it seems your problem is that you're making a cross domain request, which is blocked by most browsers due to security reasons: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

I suggest you move the code from your local computer to a place which satisfies the "Same Origin Policy", in your case that is somewhere on www.spartanbook.com.

However, there is a workaround for the problem, and that is to use [JSONP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9327218/access-control-allow-origin-not-allowed-by/12590399#answer-9327231). That will allow you to fetch JSON data from a program on another domain.