# Access Control Allow Origin not allowed by

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, cors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why am I seeing an “origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin” error here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310112/why-am-i-seeing-an-origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin-error)

I am facing problem with my code
can anyone tell me whats wrong with this
**Origin http://localhost:8080 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin**

```
var http = new getXMLHttpRequestObject();
var url = "http://gdata.youtube.com/action/GetUploadToken";
var sendXML = '<?xml version="1.0"?><entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"'+
    'xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/'+
    'xmlns:yt="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007">'+
    '<media:group><media:title type="plain">My First API</media:title>'+
    '<media:description type="plain">First API</media:description>'+
    '<media:category scheme="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat">People</media:category>'+
    '<media:keywords>first, api</media:keywords></media:group></entry>';
http.open("POST", url, true);
http.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "AuthSub token=" + AccessToken);
http.setRequestHeader("X-GData-Key", "key="+ dev_key);
http.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8");

http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(http.readyState == 4) {
        alert(http.responseXML);
    }
}
http.send(sendXML);
```