# Send data from PHP to Javascript in different domains

Tags: php, javascript, cross-domain

I send data from Javascript to PHP file using AJAX, but I couldn't take response data back from PHP to Javascript, knowing that Javascript code is in different domain than PHP code. Anyone has an idea to solve this problem?

regards,

Comment: How could your JS send data to PHP in the first place if it's in a different domain?

Comment: @MarcB: You can make outgoing AJAX requests to any domain, can't you?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access Control Allow Origin not allowed by](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9327218/access-control-allow-origin-not-allowed-by)

Comment: @xbonez: no, that's the whole point of the ajax security model. you can only have JS send a request to the same domain from which the code was loaded. Otherwise you could have a user's browser spam any site they wanted with ajax requests. It's not like google.com would say "oh, hey, this request came from some JS code loaded from yahoo.com. I'll just not respond"

Comment: @MarcB: How come I can make an AJAX request to another domain, in that case, in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/cLdGY/8/. I don't think the issue is that Google would reject the incoming request. The issue is that the response sent by Google would be rejected by Yahoo saying "I don't know where this response is coming from, so I won't trust it."

Comment: that's because it's jsonp, and it requires special support on the site you're making the request to. jsonp works around the ajax cross-domain restrictions, but you can't just fire off a jsonp request to any site you want - that site has to specifically support it.\

Answer (score 3):

To receive a response in JS cross-domain, you can either enable CORS by adding the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. However, this can be spotty.

A better solution would be to send back your response encoded as [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

Here's an example using JSONP. The API I'm calling is my own which supports JSONP responses.
[**JSONP Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/cLdGY/8/)

In contrast, the following example also works. In this case, I am not using JSONP. This request works because my API is CORS enabled. However, like I said, I have found this to be spotty, and would recommend JSONP.

[**CORS Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/cLdGY/9/)

Answer (score 1):

Cross-domain javascript can be difficult. Take a look at http://easyxdm.net/wp/

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there isn't a way to send ajax request to a different domain for security reasons.
I can think of some aproachs to workaround:

- Call a php proxy that then make the request trough sockets or curl. [Example](http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html)
- make a flash movie that call it and set a crossdomain.xml file

Comment: re: *AFAIK there isn't a way to send ajax request to a different domain for security reasons*, JSONP is the common way to do this, today.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Comment: i hadn't heard about it.Interesting, i wouldn't use it directly for security concerns though