# consuming REST API on client side using JQuery for phonegap Application

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

My code is like

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    url:  <Web Service URL>,
    data: "{}",
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function() { alert("Success"); },
    error: function() { alert('Failed!'); },
});
```

I'm trying to access the REST API from client side using JQuery but it gives error like
`XMLHttpRequest cannot load <Web Service URL>. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

So may someone help me to resolve this error..?

Comment: Hi Pushpesh, I tried the JSONP also, but it gives same error

Comment: Can you give me the url that works so that i can give it a try. The url you gave above is not working, so there is no way for me to verify.

Comment: Hi Pushpesh, it's works for me now..

Answer (score 2):

After Google for the same, I came to know that, user have to add "" in config.xml of the phonegap/hybrid application.

Answer (score 1):

Ajax requests need to be to the the server that served the web page.

What you can do is have a proxy on your website that forwards requests from the browser to the site to which you wish to make the call.

http://your.site.here/proxy/bentley/LearnService/Learnservice.svc/REST/...

So if you happened to be using apache for instance you could configure a reverse proxy by adding something like below to httpd.conf:

```
ProxyPassReverse /proxy/bentley http://khara37793punl.bentley.com/
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on other SO questions with this problem : 
[Access Control Allow Origin not allowed by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9327218/access-control-allow-origin-not-allowed-by)

And the famous : 
[Access-Control-Allow-Origin Multiple Origin Domains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653308/access-control-allow-origin-multiple-origin-domains)

All was explain on these answers, you have to allow script your server, or your script has to be on the same server.