# Bindind array of array(JSON format) to KendoUI Listview

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I am able to parse and extract the data using KendoUI when JSON is in the form 
    {
    "data" :[
    {     },
    {     },
    {     }
    ]
    }

But I am unable to do the same when JSON is in the form
    [
    {     },
    {     },
    {     }
    ]

I am trying with the following code:

```
var dataSourceSeam = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "data/address.json",
                    dataType: 'json'
                }
            }

            ,schema:{
                data : "data",
                size:"count"

            }

        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saying `data : "data"` you are saying that expect the JSON array in a field called `data`.

Try:

```
var dataSourceSeam = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: "data/address.json",
            dataType: 'json'
        }
    }
};
```

instead.

Comment: Does defining url as local address and defining it as an online Webservice url cause any difference??

Comment: No when it refers to the topic of your question. But it makes difference for the browser since it might imply [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). **BUT** as I said, this is not the topic of your question since you were asking about why using `data: "data"`.

Comment: Yes it worked perfectly..... but when i Am replacing the URL with the actual online JSON url.... it shows some error like...... not allowed by access-control-allow-origin.jquery. I know why this error, But i dont know its Workaround!!

Comment: Different question :-( Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9327218/access-control-allow-origin-not-allowed-by)